# Task Scheduler offers download of .asp script instead of running it

Tags: windows-server-2008, asp-classic, task-scheduler, asp

I scheduled this action on Task Manager on Server 2008:

Start a program
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "D:\Inetpub\pathToMy\script.asp"

When the task runs, IE opens quickly and closes, leaving behind a "Do you want to open or save this file? script.asp"

How can I run this classic ASP script?

Comment: I don't know the answer off hand, but my guess is you're going to want to Google command line asp

Comment: thanks for looking, kyle. i provided an answer below--i figured out how to do this by renaming the .asp file to .vbs.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem myself. Here's what to do:

1. rename your .asp script to .vbs
2. remove asp script start and end tags
3. remove all references to the response and request objects
4. change references to the server object to the wscript object
5. schedule your task action as the .vbs file

Details: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=188135

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll either want to Google command line asp:
http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-execute-a-dos-command/batch-file/exe-from-asp.html

Or run the location from localhost: ie, http://localhost/script.asp